# Showing data from a json file in Angular

Tags: json, angular7

This is my `home.component.ts` file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpResponse, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  cars=[];
  fetchData=function(){
    this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/cars").subscribe(
      (res:Response)=>{
        this.cars=res.json();
      }
    )
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

}
```

`home.component.html` file:

```
<h1>Cars</h1>

<table>
  <th>Id</th>
  <th>Brand</th>
  <th>Model</th>
  <tr *ngFor="let car of cars">
    <td>{{car.id}}</td>
    <td>{{car.brand}}</td>
    <td>{{car.model}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and `cars.json` file:

```
{
    "cars": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "brand": "Seat",
        "model" : "Leon"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "brand": "Mercedes",
        "model" : "AMG"
      }
    ]
}
```

I started the json server and compiled the project. The outcome is just the [table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuvWa.png) without the fetched data. The json server is listening on the 3000 port and i'm using angular 7.0.3 version. Can somebody help me?

Comment: You need to set `this.cars=res.cars;` no need to parse again, by default angular return json

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('cars.json');
let cars = JSON.parse(rawdata);
```

or

```
 const mycars = JSON.stringify(rawdata);    
 console.log(mycars);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  cars=[];
  fetchData=function(){
    this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/cars").subscribe(
      (res:Response)=>{
        this.cars=res;
      }
    )
  }
```

This fixed my problem. Thank you for the help.